# Different environment variables depending on gui or shell

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments, environment-variables

The environment variables of a program differ on whether it is started from a terminal or from the desktop (by clicking on its icon).

For example: I use bash and have specific variables set in my .bashrc for development purposes. When I start my editor of choice (sublime text, but this is true for any program) from the command line everything works fine. When I start it from the desktop (gnome 3 in this case), the variables are missing.

So my question is: What is the correct way to define variables that are honored by the desktop and the terminal alike?

Comment: take a look at this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables under "*Persistent environment variables*"

Answer (score 0):

The variables in your `.bashrc` are only set up by a `bash` shell, which, if the variables are `export`ed, stores the vars and their values in its environment, and passes a copy this environment to any process it starts. Starting `sublime text` from the desktop does not invoke `bash` to read `.bashrc`. You could set the variables globally by defining (and `export`ing) them in a `user.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d` (you will have to create `/etc/profile.d/user.sh`). If you are on a multi-user system, you could surround the definitions with `if [[ "$USER" = "me" ]] ; then ... fi`, so that everybody else (if that's a non-empty set) doesn't suffer with your definitions. Look at the other scripts in `/etc/profile.d` for hints.

To see process relationships, and environment inheritance, one could

```
pstree -a -c -l -p -u 1
```

and, of course, `man pstree`.

Comment: Well, using `~/.profile` is reasonably a more convenient option for non-global variables than conditionals in `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`.

Comment: Which programs read ~/.profile?

Comment: This is a Different Question, which should be asked on its own. But, you can ask your system which `man` pages mention `.profile` with `find /usr/share/man -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zegrep -l '\.profile'` and read them.

Comment: Good idea to search the man pages for config files. But anyway, I'm not nececarilly root on every system. Any suggestions for that case?

Comment: @dassmann: The whole `/usr/share/man` directory tree is world readable. Why do you think `root` is needed?

Comment: What I meant was that I would need root to add a file to /etc/profile.d.
Another mechanism to define variables is to use pam_env(8). There is a local config file ~/.pam_environment. Sadly, this file is not necessarily read (at least on my debian system) by default. I could fix this issue like [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/636535/pam-environment-not-loaded-in-tty), but this again requires root...